# Can 2 websites www.example.com and www.example.eu reside on the same server

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, ssl-certificate, certbot

We have 2 websites and want to get a SSL-certificate for both:

1. [www.example.de](http://www.example.de)
2. [www.otherExample.eu](http://www.otherExample.eu)

Both sites reside on the same server under different root with their own config-file. With certbot I got a certificate for each one of the sites: `sudo certbot --apache -d www.example.de -d www.otherExample.eu`

[www.example.de](http://www.example.de) works fine but [www.otherExample.eu](http://www.otherExample.eu) throws SSL-NO-CIPHER-OVERLAP-Error
Related to this question: [How to fix SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP for 2 domains on apache with certbot](https://serverfault.com/questions/1066618/how-to-fix-ssl-error-no-cypher-overlap-for-2-domains-on-apache-with-certbot)

I am aware of the fact that the handshake happens before the addressed site is known (that is why I want to have one certificate for both sites)
[Multiple SSL websites on the same Apache server](https://serverfault.com/questions/110002/multiple-ssl-websites-on-the-same-apache-server)

First question: At this point isn't it possible to get one certificate for both sites?
Second question: Could it be, that it isn't working because both sites have a different top-level-domain-name?

Final question: Is it generally possible to to get two SSL-secured sites running on one server?

Please note: We have an SNI-Server that first gets the request and sends it to the webserver.

Comment: You can have thousands of them, not just two. You should rewrite this question to ask about the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am aware of the fact that the handshake happens before the addressed site
> is known

This is wrong. This is a long solved problem and the solution is that the client sends the request URL part (or at least the domain) BEFORE the protocol negotiation. This is in place since - no idea, many many years at least - because otherwise hosters would have to reserve one IP per SSL certificate.

This is what SNI does.

> First question: At this point isn't it possible to get one certificate for
> both sites?

It actually is. I suggest instead of asking here you read - the offers of certificate providers. SAN (Subject Alternative Names) Are not something new.

> Please note: We have an SNI-Server that first gets the request and sends it
> to the webserver.

Well, if you DO have an SNI server then - bascially - it either is a broken config (which we can not magically debug for you), or broken software - the SNI server should forward with SNI enabled, too.